# Calculation of active and reactive power of grid connected converter

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, electric-machine

I have been working on [this scientific article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8863360), which is a study of a grid connected voltage source converter (VSC) illustrated in the following image.
[image]

The authors describe the VSC and the Power Grid by a simplified circuit and a phasor diagram as follows:
[image]

Based on the phasor diagram, I calculated the reactive and active power output to the grid as follows:
$$
P = \frac{3}{2}\frac{EV\sin{\delta}}{X_g}; \;\;\;\;\; Q =\frac{3}{2}\frac{EV\cos{\delta}-E^2}{X_g}
$$
these expressions are the same as for Synchronous Generator, which I think it is expected since the VSC is a voltage source, just like a Synchronous Generator. However, later on the authors define the active and reactive power with the following equations:
$$
P = \frac{3}{2}\frac{EV\sin{\delta}}{X_g}; \;\;\;\;\; Q =\frac{3}{2}\frac{V^2 -EV\cos{\delta}}{X_g}
$$

I would like to know if my calculations are wrong, or if they are correct, why do I have this slight difference between the expressions of the reactive power?

Thank you very much in advance!